# Select next/prev radio button with external button

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I'm making a sort of slideshow form, and when user click's the next image slides in, but also the radio button must be selected. I got the sliding working, and the 'next button' is working as well, but I'm kinda stuck with the 'prev' button. Don't see why it doesn't work.

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V4tdx/))

This is what I got so far, HTML:

```
<form>
<div>
    <div class="button prev">&#60;</div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="choise_1" name="first_choise" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="choise_1">One</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="choise_2" name="first_choise"/>
            <label for="choise_2">Two</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="choise_3" name="first_choise"/>
            <label for="choise_3">Three</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="button next">&#62;</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="button prev">&#60;</div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="choise_1" name="second_choise" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="choise_1">One</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="choise_2" name="second_choise"/>
            <label for="choise_2">Two</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="choise_3" name="second_choise"/>
            <label for="choise_3">Three</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="button next">&#62;</div>
</div></form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.prev').click(function(){
    $(this).next().find('input:checked').parent().prev().children('input').attr("checked", true);
    $(this).next().find('input:checked').last().removeAttr("checked");
});

$('.next').click(function(){
    $(this).prev().find('input:checked').parent().next().children('input').attr("checked", true);
    $(this).prev().find('input:checked').eq(0).parent().prev().children('input').removeAttr("checked");
});});
```

Comment: you created fiddle working,now what is your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be simplified to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.prev').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('input:checked').parent().prev().children('input').prop("checked", true);
    });

    $('.next').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('input:checked').parent().next().children('input').prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LHYJL/)

---

Same using :has-selector

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.prev').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('li:has(input:checked)').prev().children('input').prop("checked", true);
    });

    $('.next').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('li:has(input:checked)').next().children('input').prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LHYJL/2/)

Comment: Hero, this is working! Thanks! Will accept your answer when possible.

Comment: Visually it's working, but when I look to the code in the browser, the first input tag keeps having the checked attribute.. Does this affect the outcome?

Comment: @PepijnGieles no, it does not

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` and you can simplify to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.prev').click(function(){
      $(this).next().find(':checked').parent().prev().find('input').prop("checked", true);
   });

   $('.next').click(function(){
      $(this).prev().find(':checked').parent().next().find('input').prop("checked", true);
   });
});
```

Comment: Visually it's working, but when I look to the code in the browser, the first input tag keeps having the checked attribute.. Does this affect the outcome?

Comment: ohh! see if you are seeing with page source in browser then that will show you the default markup which was available at the time of page load. so at the time of page load your first input was checked so you can see that in the source but you have to use firebug/chromeinspector to see the changes.