# Trying to cycle through a group of radio buttons with Jquery using swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I am trying to use Matt Bryson's Jquery touchSwipe plugin (https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin) to advance through a group of radio buttons to show/hide content on a page.

I really just need it to go to the next radio button on left swipe and the previous radio button on right swipe, and am trying to generalize as much as possible so that it works with many button groups on the same page.

Ideally I'd like to attach it to the name of the button group and not specific IDs or Classes associated with the thing being displayed, but I can't seem to get it working. If anyone has any ideas about how this might be achieved I'd really appreciate it!

My code is below. The "you swiped..." line that's commented out is the original event from the demo and that does work...

```
$(function() {      
  //Enable swiping...
  $("#log1").swipe( {
    //LEFT SWIPE
    swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
      //$(this).text("You swiped " + direction );  
      $("input:radio[name=log1-slab-selector]").next(":checked")

    },
    //RIGHT SWIPE
    swipeRight:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
      //$(this).text("You swiped " + direction );  
      $("input:radio[name=log1-slab-selector]").prev(":checked")
    },
    //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
     threshold:0
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this related article ([Select next/prev radio button with external button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683322/select-next-prev-radio-button-with-external-button)) which helped put me on the right track, and encouraged me to wrap my buttons in a ul&li.

Unfortunately it still wasn't working, but I figured out that there was just a non semantic DIV that was getting in the way of targeting the right `li` in the tree. DAR! Once everything was moved inside the `li` it worked great!

This code fixed the issue for me:

```
$(function() {
    //Enable swiping...
    $("div#log1").swipe( {

        //LEFT SWIPE
        swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
            $(this).find('li:has(input:checked)').next('li').children('input').prop("checked", true);
        },

        //RIGHT SWIPE
        swipeRight:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
            $(this).find('li:has(input:checked)').prev('li').children('input').prop("checked", true);
        },

        //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
        threshold:25
    });
});
```