# Radio Input Control with External Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

Hello I am making a slideshow out of a radio input and have designed "prev" and "next" buttons to move the slide along. However, I would also like the buttons to also check the next input. Currently the slide moves, but the next input isn't checked. I have looked at this solution here:
[Select next/prev radio button with external button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683322/select-next-prev-radio-button-with-external-button)
and tried to implement it but I cannot get it to work.  Here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul class="form-ul" style="position: relative; width: 176px; height: 107px;">                            
      <li style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 5; opacity: 1; width: 82px; height: 43px;">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="term_id" value="59" checked="checked">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 4; opacity: 0; width: 82px; height: 62px;">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="term_id" value="61">
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="prev" style="float:left;">PREV</div> 
    <div id="next" style="float:right;">NEXT</div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#prev').click(function(){
    $('.form-ul').find('li:has(input:checked)').prev().children('input').prop("checked", true);
  });

  $('#next').click(function(){
    $('.form-ul').find('li:has(input:checked)').next().children('input').prop("checked", true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `.children()` only finds the immediate children of an element. In your case, the radio buttons are not the immediate children, so you need to change it to `.find()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#prev').click(function(){
      $('.form-ul').find('li:has(input:checked)').prev().find('input').prop("checked", true);
  });

  $('#next').click(function(){
      $('.form-ul').find('li:has(input:checked)').next().find('input').prop("checked", true);
  });
});
```

Also, you can improve performance by making less queries. Instead of

```
$('.form-ul).find('li:has(input:checked)')
```

use

```
$('.form-ul li:has(input:checked)')
```

To make it circular, check against the `length` of the result set:

```
$('#next').click(function(){
  var $next = $('.form-ul li:has(input:checked)').next();
  if(!$next.length) $next = $('.form-ul li').first();
  $next.find('input').prop("checked", true);
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/22nphfvy/) and a [circular fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/22nphfvy/1/)

Comment: Hi Yoav, your answer makes sense and looks correct, but for some reason is not working.

Comment: I have added a fiddle, check it out

Comment: Hi Yoav, it didn't work, because there was a conflict with the other javascript for the slideshow.  It works now.  Thank you very much! I upvoted you but since I am a new user and don't have enough reputation points it doesn't show.  Thanks again!

Comment: May I ask you though, is there anyway to make it circular so that after last input, if I click next again, it will go back to the original input?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer, and the fiddle to show how it's done. Also, besides upvoting you can also accept an answer.